# Break-even trades are closed with a minus (pine)

Tags: pine-script

Pine //@version=4.

I open a position and close the first take on the same bar. But the take only touches the shadow of the bar. I immediately transfer it to breakeven. The next bar opens higher than the breakeven point. And the next takes are closed with a minus. How to avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bar opened above your stop loss, so the order was triggered. This is actually a very realistic scenario, like, there is a data gap in charts or the closing price of one bar doesn't match the opening of the next bar; this can happen due to quick trades most probably other algo's.

So, since the nearest price above your stop level was the opening of the next candle, tradingview's backtester cut your position on the spot; at the opening